# Generate route with one parameter replaced

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net-core, url-routing, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have created a website where localization is being done by the first parameter in my route. So each URL looks like `/{lang}/...` with lang being `nl, en, fr, ...`.

In my header, I would like to add a language picker that redirects to the current page in the selected language. I have used the code below and it worked perfectly.

```
<a asp-route-lang="@lang.Code.ToString()">
    @lang.Name
</a>
```

However, when the current route contains other route parameters, these are all gone for the generated URL. Is there any way to tell the route generator to keep all other existing route parameters for the new URL?

I have different route definitions with different parameters, so there is no possibility to add them to the generated URL manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer of NightOwl888 gave me the idea on how to solve this.

I take the `RouteData` from the current context and use this as the base for the route generator. In my foreach loop, I overwrite the `lang` parameter with the one that I need.

Now I can use the `Url.Action()` function with this data to generate the correct URL.

```
@{
    var routeValues = this.ViewContext.RouteData.Values;
    var controller = routeValues["controller"] as string;
    var action = routeValues["action"] as string;
}

@foreach (var lang in Model.SiteLanguages)
{
    routeValues["lang"] = lang.Code.ToString();

    <a href="@Url.Action(action, controller, routeValues)">
        @lang.Name.UcFirst()
    </a>
}
```

Comment: Not sure why the option I provided doesn't work, but there is certainly nothing wrong with doing it this way. +1.

Answer (score 1):

At minimum, you need to specify a `controller` and `action` when building a URL based on routing. Since for this special case (selecting a culture) they may change depending on the URL, you need to pull these values from the current request.

```
@{
var routeValues = this.ViewContext.RouteData.Values;
var controller = routeValues["controller"] as string;
var action = routeValues["action"] as string;
}
<ul>
    <li><a asp-controller="@controller" asp-action="@action" asp-route-lang="en">English</a></li>
    <li><a asp-controller="@controller" asp-action="@action" asp-route-lang="es">Español</a></li>
</ul>
```

All other route values are carried over from the current request, so it will automatically reuse them when generating the URL, but this doesn't work for `controller` and `action`.

Comment: This still gives me the same result.

Comment: How are your routes set up? I ran this in a MVC Core project built from the Visual Studio MVC template and changed the default route to `{lang}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}` - works fine.

Comment: Also note that query string values are not automatically passed from the current request like route values are.